# Utilizing a trie Data Struture

Tags: data-structures, trie

So i am implementing a trie used for reading unique words from a file.  I was looking online on how to implement it and came across this way of doing it: 
//to insert the string in the trie tree
'

```
void insert(struct node *head, string str)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0;i < str.size(); ++i){
        //if the child node is pointing to NULL
        if(head -> next_char[str[i] - 'a'] == NULL){
            struct node *n;
            //initialise the new node
            n = new struct node;
            for(j = 0;j < 26; ++j){
                n -> next_char[j] = NULL;
            }
            n -> end_string = 0;
            head -> next_char[str[i] - 'a'] = n;
            head = n;
        }
        //if the child node is not pointing to q
        else head = head -> next_char[str[i] - 'a'];
    }
     //to mark the end_string flag for this string
    head -> end_string = 1;
}
```

My confusion arrise from the line:
'head -> next_char[str[i] - 'a'] == NULL
what is the purpose of using the subtraction of 'a' in all the ways this code implements it?

Answer (score 2):

Trie makes sense when your input strings consist of the characters from the some relatively small fixed alphabet.

In this concrete implementation it is assumed that these characters are in the range from `a`..`z`, 26 total.

As in many languages `Char` type is actually `Int` or `Byte`, you can perform arithmetic operations with it. When you do that, character's code is used as operand.

Having above in mind it is clear, that the easiest way to map chars from some known non-zero based range to zero-based range is to subtract the start element of the range from code of the particular character.

For `'a'..'z'` range:

```
 when you do ('a' - 'a') you get 0
 'b' - 'a' = 1
 ...
 'z' - 'a' = 25
```

Answer (score 0):

I add a small information beside the answer of [@Aivean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1349366/aivean) which is perfect.

- In this implementation, each node in the Trie contains a static array of size 26 to points to its children.
- The goal of this is to find the correct child in constant time, and hence check if it exists or not.
- To find the correct child (the position in the array of 26) we use current_Char - 'a' as it is well explained in [@Aivean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1349366/aivean) Answer.